# Excel count number of times a value appears in column, if unique to the row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

so I have an Excel spreadsheet that is something like this:

```
ID  A   B   C   D
1   #   £   £   £
2   #   £   £   £
3   £   #   #   #
4   £   #   #   #
5   #   £   #   #
6   £   £   £   #
7   £   #   #   #
8   #   £   £   £
9   £   £   £   £
10  #   £   #   £
```

and, for each column A-D, I want to count the number of # entries - but ONLY IF there are no other # entries in the same row - so, for example, column A has 5#, but only 3 of them are unique. Columns B and C have no unique entries, and column D has 1 unique #.

To count the hashes I would use CountIf, but I don't know how to do it when also comparing each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one for column `A` (for another columns change `A2:A11="#"` to `B2:B11="#"` and so on):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A11="#")*(MMULT(IF(A2:D11="#",1,0),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($A$2:$D$2)/COLUMN($A$2:$D$2)))=1))
```

where `A2:D11` is address of your array, `A2:A11` address of first column.

Note, since it's an array formula, you should press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

[image]

Comment: nice! I haven't used Array formulae before - thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you could do this with a single sumproduct and I'm still playing around with that, but as a quick fix, if you could use a helper column, you could do something like this:

1. In `E1`, put in the following formula: `=COUNTIF($A1:$D1,"#")` and drag it down
2. in your test cell - say `A12`, put in the following formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A10="#"),--($E$1:$E$10=1))` and drag it across to column D.

That will give you the results `3   0   0   1` as expected, but I'm still sure there's a nicer way....

Hope this helps, though!

Comment: That's a good start, thanks. Doing it without the helper column would make my spreadsheet tidier though

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula in A13 copied across to D13

`=SUMPRODUCT((MMULT((A2:A11="#")*($A2:$D11="#"),{1;1;1;1})=1)+0)`

This doesn't require "array entry"

the `{1;1;1;1}` part will need to change depending on the number of columns in your range - there are four 1s here because your whole range is four columns. If you want to make that part automatic you can switch to this "array formula"

`=SUM((MMULT((A2:A11="#")*($A2:$D11="#"),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($A2:$D11)^0))=1)+0)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

or another way is like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A11="#")*(COUNTIF(OFFSET($A2:$D2,ROW(A2:A11)-ROW(A2),0),"#")=1))`

All of those formulas should give the same result